# What are the Home automation prerequisites?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, home-automation

I want to design a home automation system. I want to include some basic features to that system like

```
1. Light on/off
2. Fan on/off and speed control
3. AC on/off
4. Water pump on/off 
5. CCTV camera monitor
```

What should the basic things I should study before starting? I decided to use Raspberry Pi3 and PIC microcontroller. Is it the right decision or I should change platform?? Any advice  will be highly obliged.

Comment: it depends on the hardware you can get to do this, the switches, etc, then from that list pick one or more interfaces/protocols, then from that list what control platforms are available.  starting with the cart first is not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Raspberry Pi project for house automation called FEHM. `http://fhem.de/fhem.html` 
You can include your own functions, modules, systems and it's also god for study the basic things of a home automation system. If you plan to build your own system.

> FHEM (TM) is a GPL'd perl server for house automation. It is used to
>   automate some common tasks in the household like switching lamps /
>   shutters / heating / etc. and to log events like temperature /
>   humidity / power consumption.
>
> The program runs as a server, you can control it via web or smartphone
>   frontends, telnet or TCP/IP directly.
>
> In order to use FHEM you'll need a 24/7 server (Fritz!Box, NAS, RPi,
>   PC, MacMini, etc) with a perl interpreter and some attached hardware
>   like the CUL, FHZ1300PC, etc. to access the actors and sensors. See
>   the "Supported hardware" section below.
>
> It is pronounced without the h, like in feminine.

Answer (score 0):

1) through 4) are not an issue for the Pi3. It has sufficient "power" to do all those things for any reasonable number of tasks one could think of. The limited amount of GPIO pins may dictate a careful design but I2C and port expanders and what-not will overcome those issues. For any specific questions be sure to join https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

How well the Pi will handle 5) "CCTV camera monitor" boils down to the number of cameras, their resolution, and respective frame rate. Performance limits either from CPU, disk I/O, or ethernet transfer rate may arise. My advice would therefore be to study those issues first (`zoneminder` and `motion` come to mind).